# Make qmail dequeue only during certain time period per day

Tags: qmail

I am using qmail to send a large number of emails on behalf of many people. It varies between 400k and 600k emails per job.

A `php` script queues up all of the messages, which takes a few hours. The messages then take about 24-48 hours to dequeue and get sent.

The length of time is not a problem, but I do not like that emails are sent at odd times (like in the middle of the night, or at sunrise).

**Is there a way I can tell qmail to only dequeue messages only during a certain time range?**

For example, tell it to only empty the queue between 6AM and 8PM, then just let it "sleep" after 8PM until 6AM the next day to finish the queue.

*Using CentOS 6.6 Final*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `qmailctl pause` will pause qmail, and `qmailctl cont` will unpause.

If that's too much, a look at the source show this:

```
pause)
  echo "Pausing qmail-send"
  svc -p /service/qmail-send
  echo "Pausing qmail-smtpd"
  svc -p /service/qmail-smtpd
  ;;
```

Doing `svc -p /service/qmail-send` should prevent qmail from sending, and then `svc -c /etc/service/qmail-send` to go back to normal. You could use a cron job to perform these actions at times of your choosing.